# Collections.reverse doesn't work correctly

Tags: java

I defined a list class that wraps int[] like this.

```
class IntList extends AbstractList<Integer> {
    private final int[] array;
    public IntList(int[] array) { this.array = array; }
    @Override public int size() { return array.length; }
    @Override public Integer get(int i) { return array[i]; }
    @Override public Integer set(int i, Integer e) { return array[i] = e; }
}
```

And I tried to reverse int[].

```
int[] array = {4, 2, 0, 1, 3};
List<Integer> list = new IntList(array);
System.out.println("list=" + list);
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println("reversed list=" + list);
System.out.println("reversed array=" + Arrays.toString(array));
```

The results are

```
list=[4, 2, 0, 1, 3]
reversed list=[4, 2, 0, 2, 4]
reversed array=[4, 2, 0, 2, 4]
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return the replaced element in `set`:

```
@Override public Integer set(int i, Integer e) { 
  int res = array[i];
  array[i] = e; 
  return res;
}
```

Otherwise, `return array[i] = e;` returns `e`. This breaks the `reverse`, because for example, in first step:

- last `3` is overridden by replaced `4`
- a `4` is returned instead of `3`
- this `4` is placed at the first position
- You end up with two `4`s both in first and last element.